# change http responses and body responses from apache camel

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, spring-camel

i have 2 routes:

```
<route id="test1">
            <from uri="direct:start" />
            <setProperty propertyName="id">
                <simple>${header._id}</simple>
            </setProperty>
            <setBody>
                <simple>${in.headers._id}</simple>
            </setBody>                  
            <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
            <log logName="test" message="id : ${body}" />
            <to uri="file://inbox"/>
        </route>

<route id="tesst" streamCache="true">
        <from uri="file://inbox" />
        <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
        <log logName="test"
            message="from inbox: ${body}" />
        <setProperty propertyName="test">
            <simple>${body}</simple>
        </setProperty>
        <to
            uri="sql: SELECT blabla FROM blabla WHERE test = :#${property.test}" />
        <setProperty propertyName="result">
            <simple>${body}</simple>
        </setProperty>
        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>${property.result} != ""</simple>
                <log logName="test"
                    message="call procedure.." />
                <to uri="sql: CALL public.sp_test(:#${property.test})" />

            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <log logName="test" message="Data not found!" />
                <setHeader headerName="Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE">
                    <constant>404</constant>
                </setHeader>
                <camel:setBody>
                    <simple resultType="java.lang.String">Data not found!</simple>
                </camel:setBody>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </route>
```

when i insert the wrong data, the http response i get still 200. i want to make http response 404 after some  validation in choice-when-otherwise check. i already tried setheader, setheaderout, but none of them works. how can i do that?

Comment: It makes no sense to set status code with file consumer. It will be never propagated. You need to handle this in http route (which you haven't included in question, so it is not possible to give you correct answer)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @bedla in the comments, a File consumer (in-only messaging) cannot send a response. So it is hard to understand your case.

However, if you implement an HTTP server (consumer; in-out messaging) with Camel, you can set the HTTP status code of the response as message header

```
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(404))
```